# Permission error in software center on clean Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, ubuntu-18.04, software-update

I need to install the "*hide top bar*" extension on a clean installation of *Ubuntu 18.04*. After I open the software center I get his error message on the top under the search bar:

```
Unable to download updates: you do not have permission to install software
```

When I try to search for "hide top bar" it does not find anything, even though it works on my other machines and virtual machines.

I have tried so far:

- Rebooting
- sudo apt update
- sudo apt upgrade

Note: The user is set to auto login on startup

Comment: I use Ubuntu 18.04 Mate and I prefer `Synaptic` for software installation searches. If you don't have it already, you can install with `sudo apt install synaptic`.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue when trying to install software. Right now I am using a work around by just running- `sudo gnome-software`.